# Why need a server for running GraphQL

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I am totally new in GraphQL. So many things are confusing for me like why i need a server for running GraphQL as why some library doesn't sort out the implementation. 
As far as i know server is for respond data. So what else it will do for GraphQL.

Answer (score 3):

> GraphQL is a query language for APIs and a runtime for fulfilling
>   those queries with your existing data. GraphQL provides a complete and
>   understandable description of the data in your API, gives clients the
>   power to ask for exactly what they need and nothing more, makes it
>   easier to evolve APIs over time, and enables powerful developer tools.

https://graphql.org/

Essentially, you have a client side and a server side. The client requests (query) data from the server, or requests the server to update data (mutation). If you're working on the client side only, you don't need a server (given it already exists).

This link may also be helpful: https://www.apollographql.com/why-graphql

Hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

As you note, it's "just" a query language, and you don't need a server *per se*.  For example, in the reference graphql-js implementation, you can [just call `graphql` with a query](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/graphql/#graphql); similarly, in graphql-ruby, you can [`#execute` a query on a schema object](http://graphql-ruby.org/queries/executing_queries.html).

The usual case for GraphQL "in the wild" is as an API layer, though.  You'd have a GraphQL interface over a native database, or as an alternative to a REST API.  In both of those cases if you were calling something from the same system you wouldn't usually go through GraphQL just to translate it into, say, SQL; you'd directly call the database layer.

You might compare GraphQL to to SQL, where there are also [library-based implementations](https://sqlite.org/) but the query language is the *only* way to interact with the system; and also to other API layers like SOAP, which use HTTP as a minimal transport layer but don't really use the full expressiveness of the protocol.